# Unable to use chosen-select on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Has two chosen-select in page one should be on window. And its working fine.
when i click on  .btn-sm (button)  to load on light window/popup chosen-select loading data but unable to select

What I am doing wrong?

HTML (window):

```
<div class ="form-group">
    <label for="deptselection" class="col-sm-4 control-label id">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <!-- chosen-select"  data-placeholder="Choose a Doctor..."  tabindex="2" -->
        <!-- selectpicker" data-size="5"  data-live-search="true" -->
        <select id ="catgselection" multiple = "" name="catgselection[]" class="form-control chosen-select"  data-placeholder="Choose a Category..."  tabindex="2">
            <?php
                if(!empty($catg)) 
                {
                    $i=1;
                    foreach ($catg as $key => $value) 
                    {
                        echo "<option value=".$value->id.">".$value->category."</option>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            ?>                        
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Html:Light window/pop up

```
<div class ="form-group">
    <label for="catgselection_ed" class="col-sm-4 control-label id">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <!-- chosen-select"  data-placeholder="Choose a Doctor..."  tabindex="2" -->
        <!-- selectpicker" data-size="5"  data-live-search="true" -->
        <select id ="catgselection_ed" multiple = "" name="catgselection_ed[]" class="form-control chosen-select2"  data-placeholder="Choose a Category..."  tabindex="2">
            <?php
            if(!empty($catg)) 
            {
                $i=1;
                foreach ($catg as $key => $value) 
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$value->id.">".$value->category."</option>";
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            ?>                        
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen(); // for main window

            $('.scroll').scrolltable({
                stripe: true,
                oddClass: 'odd'
            });
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".btn-sm" , function() {
            $(".chosen-select2").chosen(); // for light window
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it might be due to the css issues..please try to figure the style...most probaly the giving z-index to the new choosen select box might work